# Question about $|x+6|\leq 10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Why does $|x+6|\leq 10$ in interval notation equal $[-16,4]$ and not $(-\infty,-16]\cup[4,\infty)$?

Also, can you please explain to me the difference between $\cup$ and $\cap$?

Comment: Welcome to SE! $\cup$ is the union of sets,meaning that you should join their elements together. Example: $\{1,2\} \cup \{2,3,4\} =\{1,2,3,4\}$. $\cap$ is the intersection, meaning that you take common elements present in all sets. Example: $\{1,2\} \cap \{2,3,4\} = \{2\}$

Comment: The way to "solve" this problem is really only by knowing the *definition* of absolute value. That is, do you know what $|x|$ really means and how you would represent this algebraically? Once you know that, then you can realize that $|x+6|\leq10$ is the same as writing $-10\leq x+6\leq 10$. Then you subtract $6$ from all sides, as in my answer. There is no need here for $\cup$ or $\cap$. Nonetheless, the *difference* between these symbols is that $\cup$ stands for "or" or "union" and $\cap$ stands for "and" or "intersection."

Comment: Please note that $(-\infty , -16 ] \cup [4, \infty) \neq [-16,4]$.

Comment: @user46944 Fixed, thanks, forgot to escape.

Comment: I understand the union and intersection concepts but I am still confused about writing the interval notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
|x+6|\leq 10&\iff -10\leq x+6\leq 10\tag{by defn.}\\[0.5em]
&\iff -16\leq x\leq 4\tag{subtract $6$ throughout}\\[0.5em]
&\iff x\in[-16,4].
\end{align}

Comment: Ok, but why does |x+3| ≥ 8 = (-∞, -11] ∪ [5, ∞) ?

Comment: @MattButler That's a *different* question, something you should post separately from your question here. But anyhow, for $|x+3|\geq 8$, you will have that $x+3\geq 8$ **or** $x+3\leq -8$. Now subtract $3$ from both sides of both inequalities; doing so will yield that $x\geq 5$ **or** $x\leq -11$. In interval notation, this means we have that $|x+3|\geq 8=(-\infty,-11]\cup[5,\infty)$.

Comment: So essentially the ≥ constitutes for an or statement thus forcing you to complete the interval by adding ∞ or -∞ ?

Comment: Why should the OP post that as a new question? Through their comment, they are explaining their confusion at its heart: why some problems have answers with unions in them and others don't.  It's not at all a different question.

Comment: @user46944 The *new* question is just that--a *new* question. I don't have any problem expanding on it (just as I did here), but new questions should not be asked in comments, and the answer to OP's new question here is actually addressed in your own answer. Hopefully OP read your answer because then what I wrote above should make sense.

Comment: @MattButler Please see my answer.  When you have $|\text{stuff}| \geq a$, you have different rules than if you have $|\text{stuff}| \leq a$.  You get an "or" when you have the first case, and the "or" turns into a $\cup$ in the end.  So $|x + 3| \geq 8$ means by the rules in my answer that $x + 3 \geq 8$ or $x + 3 \leq -8$.  Then $x \geq 5$ or $x \leq -11$.  The first part of the "or" is $[5, \infty)$.  The second part is $(-\infty, -11]$.  And the "or" means $\cup$, so the answer is $(-\infty, -11] \cup [5, \infty)$.

Comment: @MattButler You seem to be alright with having reached the point that $x\geq 5$ or $x\leq -11$. To see how $\pm\infty$ fits in, simply consider this: give me *any* negative never less than or equal to $-11$, and I bet I can give you an even bigger negative number (that is, $x$ can go from $-\infty$ to $-11$). Now do this for positive values. Give me any positive integer greater than or equal to $5$, and I bet I can give you back an even large positive integer. That is, $x$ can go from $5$ to $\infty$. Does that make more sense?

Comment: @user46944 Saying that "the 'or' turns into a $\cup$ at the end" is a little misleading and possibly confusing in my opinion. The $\cup$ **is** an "or" or a disjunction. Same goes with interpreting something like $\lor, \land$ and how they are the same as $\cup,\cap$, respectively.

Comment: I think that I understand it now after reading both Daniel's and user's comments. With a ≤ you only need 1 interval so there is no need to gather more values. But with the ≥ it is referred to as an or statement so essentially there will be 4 vales (you get 2 and the rest and ranges) Am I thinking correctly?

Comment: @MattButler Yeah, that sounds right!  Good job :)

Comment: I appreciate your help guys. Wish I could give you both the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Think of $\cup$ as meaning "or" as in $A \cup B$ means all the elements in $A$ or $B$ or both. $\cap$ is like "and" as in $A \cap B$ means all the elements in both $A$ and $B$. For example, let

$A = \{ 1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B = \{ 4,5,6,7 \}$.

Then $A \cup B = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and $A \cap B = \{ 4,5\}$.

As far as the inequality goes:

$$|x+6| \leq 10$$
$$-10 \leq x+6 \leq 10$$
$$-16 \leq x \leq 4$$

which means $x\in[ -16,4]$

Answer (score 1):

It is clearest with the geometrical interpretation of the absolute value: $\lvert x+6\rvert$ is the distance from the point $x$ to $-6$. The inequation means this distance is no more than $10$, in one direction or the other. In numbers, this means 
$$-10\le x-(-6)\le 10\iff -6-10\le x\le -6+10.$$

Comment: +1 for geometric interpretation. (Although you want to change all your inequalities from $<$ to $\leq$.)

Comment: @SimonS About geometric interpretation: that's why my comment on OP's question was meant to encourage :p It's interesting to me how many problems are caused for people concerning absolute value problems when the simple solution almost always seems to be in understanding 1) the absolute value concept geometrically and 2) the algebraic definition.

Comment: Yes. I recently started tutoring the 13 year old son of a neighbor. He has had to work absolute value problems and it has significantly helped to demystify the  mathematics by going back to "geometric first principles" of measurement on a number line.

Comment: The most enlightening problem  is asking things like ‘Solve for $\;\lvert x+6\rvert <\lvert x-2\rvert$’, which seems quite fearsome to young people and is trivial from the geometric point of view, if you extrapolate it to a problem in two deimensions.

Answer (score 0):

**PLEASE** do not confuse the rules for the inequalities $|\text{stuff}| \geq a$ and $|\text{stuff}| \leq a$.

For $|\text{stuff}| \leq a$, this means: $$-a \leq \text{stuff} \leq a.$$

For $|\text{stuff}| \geq a$, this means:

$$\text{stuff} \geq a \text{  or } \text{stuff} \leq -a.$$

So, here our "stuff" is $x + 6$, and $a$ is $10$, and we have the **first case**, so that means we have:

$|x + 6| \leq 10$ means $-10 \leq x + 6 \leq 10$.

Finally, to "solve" for $x$, subtract $6$ from all sides to get:

$-10 - 6 \leq x + 6 - 6 \leq 10 - 6$

which gives us:

$-16 \leq x \leq 4$

and in interval notation, this stands for the interval $[-16, 4]$.